# Install Magento without database

Tags: php, html, database, magento, magento-1.8

How to install Magento and skip the database validation? I don't need sales order, shipping, etc. Just wanna make a Magento as a CMS module.

Or, any best CMS that running lightly?

i've tried Magento Lite but there's an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you mean by "skip the database validation". But if you want to use Magento as a cms and have the sales and other modules stripped [I recommend this](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite).
It's a Magento version that has stripped the catalog, sales, customers and many others.
I've tested it and it runs smoothly.

[EDIT]

If you are asking about any CMS in general or looking for one that runs lightly, then I think this is completely off topic and to broad for any answer to cover it.
Each CMS has it's advantages and disadvantages.
I think you shouldn't base your search for a CMS on its "lightness". This should be a secondary reason. First you have to find the ones that fit your needs and then compare them.

[Start looking here for example.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP)

Comment: Hi there, i got some errors. 
Warning: include(Zend\Log.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \htdocs\magentolite\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Zend\Log.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\magentolite\app\code\local;D:\xampp\htdocs\magentolite\app\code\community;htdocs\magentolite\app\code\core;\htdocs\magentolite\lib;.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\magentolite\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93

Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in \htdocs\magentolite\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 247

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano Read this. https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-lite#installation. The repository does not include the ZF needed to run Magento. It is included as a git submodule.